# Radio button con su input text

Tags: javascript, html

Me gustaría saber que puedo hacer para que los input radio funcione con su respectivo input text, ya que los 4 botones interactuan con un mismo input text y me causa conflicto a la hora de realizar un formulario mas grande. Espero y puedan ayudarme y gracias de antemano.

```js
//esperamos a que cargue el DOM
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {


  //seleccionamos los inputs tipo radio, recuerda que 
  //esto te trae un HTMLCollections, así que lo tienes que recorrer con un for
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');

  //console.log(inputs[0]);

  //cremos el for
  for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
    //le agregamos a cada iteración un addEventListener de tipo change
    //como su nombre lo indica al momento de cambiar de input tomará su valor
    inputs[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
      //Validamos que ese input tenga el atributo checked
      if (this.checked) {
        //si es así obtenemos su valor y lo agregamos al input.
        document.getElementById("rInput").value = this.value;
      }
    })
})
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>javascript - Obtain the value of a radio button</title>


</head>

<body>
  <h1>Obtain the value of a radio button</h1>
  <form id="form1">
    <p>Deacuerdo: Si<input type="radio" name="deacuerdo" value="si"> No<input type="radio" name="deacuerdo" value="no"></p>

    <div id="resultado"><input id="rInput" type="text"></div>
    <p>Enterado: Si se<input type="radio" name="enterado" value="si se"> No se<input type="radio" name="enterado" value="no se"></p>

    <div id="resultados"><input id="eInput" type="text"></div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo comentado la parte del código que agregué y también hice modificaciones a tu HTML, lo que hice fue guardar los primeros dos radios y el input `text` correspondiente en un div y en el otro caso igual, para saber en que div se encuentra el input `text` al que le quiero agregar el valor de su radio, espero te sirva, cualquier duda hazla saber.

```js
//esperamos a que cargue el DOM
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {


  //seleccionamos los inputs tipo radio, recuerda que 
  //esto te trae un HTMLCollections, así que lo tienes que recorrer con un for
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');

  //console.log(inputs[0]);

  //cremos el for
  for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
    //le agregamos a cada iteración un addEventListener de tipo change
    //como su nombre lo indica al momento de cambiar de input tomará su valor
    inputs[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
      //Validamos que ese input tenga el atributo checked
      if (this.checked) {
      
      console.log(this.value);
      //Con parentNode recorremos el arbol de un nodo hijo a el padre, 
      //en este caso hay que recorrerlo dos veces 
      //ya que si lo hacemos una vez seleccionamos el <p></p> 
      //y nosotros necesitamos saber qué div se encuentra tanto 
      //el radio seleccionado como el input text
      let divPadre = this.parentNode.parentNode.id;
      
      //utilizando strings literals concatenamos la variable divPadre 
      //la cuál contiene "div1" o "div2" y mediante querySelectorAll 
      //buscamos el input que está dentro del div especificado y le agregamos su valor.
      document.querySelectorAll(`#${divPadre} input[type="text"]`)[0].value = this.value;
      
        //si es así obtenemos su valor y lo agregamos al input.
        //document.getElementById("rInput").value = this.value;
      }
    })
})
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>javascript - Obtain the value of a radio button</title>


</head>

<body>
  <h1>Obtain the value of a radio button</h1>
  <form id="form1">
  <div id="div1">
    <p>Deacuerdo: Si<input type="radio" name="deacuerdo" value="si"> No<input type="radio" name="deacuerdo" value="no"></p>

   <input id="rInput" type="text"></div>
    <div id="div2">
    <p>Enterado: Si se<input type="radio" name="enterado" value="si se"> No se<input type="radio" name="enterado" value="no se"></p>

    <input id="eInput" type="text"></div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, corrigiendo tu código solo falta agregar en la condición if el name, para diferenciarlos uno de otro y así, escribir su value en el textbox correspondiente.

Añado ejemplo

```js
//esperamos a que cargue el DOM
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {


  //seleccionamos los inputs tipo radio, recuerda que 
  //esto te trae un HTMLCollections, así que lo tienes que recorrer con un for
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');

  //console.log(inputs[0]);

  //cremos el for
  for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
    //le agregamos a cada iteración un addEventListener de tipo change
    //como su nombre lo indica al momento de cambiar de input tomará su valor
    inputs[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
      //Validamos que ese input tenga el atributo checked
      if (this.checked && this.name =="deacuerdo") {
        //si es así obtenemos su valor y lo agregamos al input.
        document.getElementById("rInput").value = this.value;
      }else{
        document.getElementById("eInput").value = this.value;
      }
    })
})
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>javascript - Obtain the value of a radio button</title>


</head>

<body>
  <h1>Obtain the value of a radio button</h1>
  <form id="form1">
    <p>Deacuerdo: Si<input type="radio" name="deacuerdo" value="si"> No<input type="radio" name="deacuerdo" value="no"></p>

    <div id="resultado"><input id="rInput" type="text"></div>
    <p>Enterado: Si se<input type="radio" name="enterado" value="si se"> No se<input type="radio" name="enterado" value="no se"></p>

    <div id="resultados"><input id="eInput" type="text"></div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: En caso de querer hacer una tercera opción, se tiene que agregar otro else o como sería?

Comment: Una tercera opción modificaría un poco el código y como dices, se podría agregar otro `else` que defina otro nombre, existen varios métodos para detectar cambios, lo mas eficiente es si es que tienes muchas opciones, realizar la detección de forma independiente por cada grupo `checkbox`. Este ejemplo fue para tu caso particular de solo 2 opciones. PD: Si te sirve la respuesta, no olvides marcarla como correcta con el `tick` verde bajo los votos de la respuesta.

Comment: Amigo, recuerda marcar la solución si resolvió tu problema, ya que tu duda puede ser la duda de alguien más.